# Exclude option doesn't work properly by Dart Analyzer

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-analyzer

I am using the Flutter INTL package in my app for internationalization. The package generates a `generated` folder and I want the analyzer to ignore it.

I followed the [Exclude code from analysis article](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#excluding-code-from-analysis) however, it seems it doesn't work as two of the generated files won't be disappeared from the list.

[image]

This is my pubspec.yaml file.

```
name: luma_app
description: Luma My Account

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

  # Firebase related libraries
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3         # https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.2.4  # https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics
  firebase_analytics: ^6.3.0    # https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1      # https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4      # https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore
  firebase_storage: ^5.2.0      # https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage

  # Internationalization package helps us to manage different languages
  intl: ^0.16.1                 # https://pub.dev/packages/intl

  provider: ^4.3.2+3            # https://pub.dev/packages/provider
  google_fonts: ^1.1.1          # https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts
  package_info: ^0.4.3+2        # https://pub.dev/packages/package_info/install
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4 # https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences
  get_it: ^5.0.3                # https://pub.dev/packages/get_it
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.1          # https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg
  native_pdf_view: ^3.9.0       # https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_view

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  pedantic: ^1.9.2              # https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic
#  effective_dart: ^1.3.0        # https://pub.dev/packages/effective_dart

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  generate: true # This is for localizations. Don't remove it.

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/google_fonts/
    - assets/images/

flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
```

and finally, this is the content of my analysis_options.yaml file.

```
# For more information visit:
# https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

#include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml
# or
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.1.9.0.yaml
#include: package:effective_dart/analysis_options.1.3.0.yaml

analyzer:
  exclude:
    - lib/generated/**
#  strong-mode:
#    implicit-casts: false
#    implicit-dynamic: false
#  errors:
#    prefer_single_quotes: ignore

linter:
  rules:
    - camel_case_types
```

Dart/OS versions:

```
==> dart --version
Dart SDK version: 2.10.4 (stable) (Wed Nov 11 13:35:58 2020 +0100) on "macos_x64"
```

Comment: Have you restarted the analyzer since changing the file?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, I thought it is an automatic process. Isn't it? I am saying this because I had a long list of issues (including these two) and they disappeared after I fixed issues automatically. If it is manual or there is a way then how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the documentation needs to be updated. You just need to remove `lib/` from the path. So this configuration would work:

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - generated/**
```